# CPU Solo Mining on ARM

Tags: miner-configuration, cpuminer

I am playing around with bitcoin mining. I have set up a full node on an ODroid C2 device. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and Bitcoin core. That seems to be running find. It is keeping up with the block chain with no errors.

I downloaded the cpuminer source and built it without errors.

When I run it it starts up the 4 mining threads, but always gives and error that the host returned a 404 error.

I have the rpc set up and am using the correct username and password.

I am using the default ip address for localhost and the default port of 8882.

Can someone explain what I have done wrong that minerd won't connect to the local bitcoin node?

Answer (score -1):

The ability to solo mine was removed some time ago. You have to set up a stratum proxy server.

Comment: Mining code (`setgenerate`) was removed from Bitcoin Core itself, but the API (`getblocktemplate`) to interface to an external program for solo mining still remains.  In principle it should be possible to use it, so I think OP's problem is something else.